# angularjs select list dynamic id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select list bound to a property, the list items are created via a function on the `$root` scope and accessed in the `ng-options` attribute. For some reason I am unable to set the select list ID using the below expression when `ng-options` is used.

I have tried removing `ng-options` and the ID generates correctly. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
<label for="app.prop.{{$index}}">State</label>
<select id="app.prop.{{$index}}" name="app.prop" class="form-control" ng-model="app.prop" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in SomeList()"></select>
```

Comment: why dots in ID and name? Using dot in element ID makes little sense. Might not be good using same `name` as `ng-model`

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem with AngularJS 1.2.0. I updated the version I use to the latest stable (1.2.9) and this issue now seems to be fixed.